How to find error when define model sequelize?
I first time use sequelize. I define two models but after run show error. I dont know how to fix this. help me please. GalleryType model:
const GalleryType = sequelize.define("gallerytype",{
    _id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    title:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        
        unique: {
            arg:true,
            name: 'Unique field',
            msg: "Gallery type must be unique"
        }
    }
})
GalleryType.hasMany(Gallery, {foreignKey: 'type', onDelete: 'CASCADE'})

Gallery model:
const Gallery = sequelize.define("gallery",{
    _id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    title:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    picture: DataTypes.STRING,
    url:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})
Gallery.belongsTo(GalleryType, { foreignKey: 'type', targetKey: '_id' });


Error: gallery.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model


You just have a circular dependency between models and you simply need to move all association definitions outside the model modules and place them all in the module where you have all models already registered, see my other answer here to get the whole idea
